# How to show label to appear off the page when using StackLayout

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a gesture to swipe left and I would like the label to appear like it is swiped off the screen.

How does one achieve this with xamarin forms?
[image]

For example in the picture below the item selected was "Check the trains schedule London - Paris"

When the item is selected the text appears off the screen.  I would like to achieve the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a lovely grid with 2 columns.

**EDIT** This grid is going to sit inside a horizontal scrollview. This is what makes the trick to go out of the screen possible. 
Now if you want to prohibit user from manually scrolling your ScrollView use a custom renderer. But this is not needed in case you want the user to be able to swipe the control left-right, it then acts rather naturally. So in XAML code below you can just use `ScrollView` instead of `controls:DisabledScrollView`.

1st column is what you have on the screen.
2nd column is what is hidden out of the screen.
First col width = ScreenSize. Define in code as it can change dynamically on screen rotation.
Second column width - at will. In your case it's small for just this TrashCan icon.
I'm managing it in the OnSize changed event for the grid, the invoked `OnSizeChanged_TitleBarMain` from XAML:

```
            cNavBarSlider.ColumnDefinitions.Clear();    
            cNavBarSlider.ColumnDefinitions.Add(
                new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(ScreenWidth, GridUnitType.Absolute) }
                );
            cNavBarSlider.ColumnDefinitions.Add(
                new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(ScreenWidth - popupSearchOffset, GridUnitType.Absolute) }
            );

            //reposition scroll if needed (on screen rotation)
            if (IsPopupSearchVisible)
            {
                await cNavBarSlider.TranslateTo(-ScreenWidth + popupSearchOffset, 0, 0, null);
            }
```

Slide this table left-right with TranslateTo, in my case it was:

```
await cNavBarSlider.TranslateTo(-cTitleBarMain.Width + popupSearchOffset, 0, PopupOptionsTimeIn, Easing.CubicInOut);
```

Both IconSearch and Cancel hotspots (using hotspots and i want larger area to respond to touch, instead of user trying to tap some small icon or small word) invoke same method:

```
private bool _tapped;
    //-------------------------------------------------------------
    private async void OnTapped_SearchIcon(object sender, EventArgs e)
    //-------------------------------------------------------------
    {
        if (_tapped) return;
        _tapped = true;
        if (!IsPopupSearchVisible) await PopupSearchShow();
        else await PopupSearchHide();
        _tapped = false;
    }
//-------------------------------------------------------------------
public async Task PopupSearchShow()
//-------------------------------------------------------------------
{
    await PopupSearchInit();
    await cNavBarSlider.TranslateTo(-cTitleBarMain.Width + popupSearchOffset, 0, PopupOptionsTimeIn, Easing.CubicInOut);
    IsPopupSearchVisible = true;
    ControlSearchEntry.Focus();
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------
public async Task PopupSearchHide(bool animate = true)
//-------------------------------------------------------------------
{
    uint d = PopupOptionsTimeOut;
    if (!animate) d = 0;
    await cNavBarSlider.TranslateTo(0, 0, d, Easing.CubicInOut);
    IsPopupSearchVisible = false;
}
```

**The XAML scheme to play with:**

```
        <!--  SWIPE CONTAINER  -->
        <controls:DisabledScrollView Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Grid
                x:Name="cNavBarSlider"
                ColumnSpacing="0"
                HorizontalOptions="Fill">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <!--  this in on screen, going to swipe -->
                <Grid
                    x:Name="cTitleBarMain"
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    SizeChanged="OnSizeChanged_TitleBarMain">
                    <!--  put ur stuff here  -->
                </Grid>

                <StackLayout
                    x:Name="cTitleBarSearch"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <!-- your hidden content to appear put here --!>
                <StackLayout>

            </Grid>
        </controls:DisabledScrollView>
```

[image: iOS Xamarin.Forms pure xaml+code page nor renderers]

**EDIT**

Here's your code in list (Android emulator) note you can implement swipes to limit the scrolling coordinates, to make it sticky to bounds:

[image]

Listview:

```
    <ListView
        x:Name="MainList"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
        BackgroundColor="{StaticResource ColorListView}"
        HasUnevenRows="False"
        RowHeight="40"
        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
        IsVisible="{Binding IsOffline, Converter={StaticResource not}}"
        ItemSelected="MainList_OnItemSelected"
        RefreshCommand="{Binding ForceRefreshCommand}">
        <ListView.SeparatorColor>
            <OnPlatform
                x:TypeArguments="Color"
                WinPhone="{StaticResource ListSeparator}"
                iOS="{StaticResource ListSeparator}" />
        </ListView.SeparatorColor>

        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>

                <appoMobi:CellJessica/>

            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Cell XAML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ViewCell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="AppoMobi.CellJessica"
      x:Name="MyViewCell">
    <!--  SWIPE CONTAINER  -->
    <StackLayout SizeChanged="OnSizeChanged_TitleBarMain" x:Name="cCell" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">

        <ScrollView x:Name="scrollView" 
                        Orientation="Horizontal" 
                        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Grid x:Name="cNavBarSlider"
                      ColumnSpacing="0"
                      HorizontalOptions="Fill">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <!--  this in on screen, going to swipe -->
                <Grid 
                    x:Name="cTitleBarMain"
                    Grid.Column="0">
                    <!--  put ur stuff here  -->
                    <Label x:Name="txtLabel" TextColor="Black" />
                </Grid>

                <StackLayout
                    x:Name="cTitleBarSearch"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="cake" HeightRequest="35" WidthRequest="35"   VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Start" />
                </StackLayout>

            </Grid>
        </ScrollView>

    </StackLayout>
</ViewCell>
```

Cell Code:

```
   public partial class CellJessica
    {
        public CellJessica()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        //-------------------------------------------------------------
        protected override void OnBindingContextChanged()
        //-------------------------------------------------------------
        {
            SetupCell();
            base.OnBindingContextChanged();
        }

        private bool first_setup = true;
        //-------------------------------------------------------------
        public void SetupCell()
        //-------------------------------------------------------------
        {

            var item = BindingContext as CSalonListItemEx;
            if (item == null) return;


            txtLabel.Text = item.Name;

        }
        private bool _titlebar_changingsize = false;

        private double popupSearchOffset = 0;
        //-------------------------------------------------------------------
        private async void OnSizeChanged_TitleBarMain(object sender, EventArgs e)
            //-------------------------------------------------------------------
        {
            if (_titlebar_changingsize) return;
            _titlebar_changingsize = true;

            cNavBarSlider.ColumnDefinitions.Clear();
            cNavBarSlider.ColumnDefinitions.Add(
                new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(cCell.Width, GridUnitType.Absolute) }
            );
            cNavBarSlider.ColumnDefinitions.Add(
            //new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(cCell.Width - popupSearchOffset, GridUnitType.Absolute) }
                new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(40, GridUnitType.Absolute) }
            );

            //todo
            //reposition scroll if rotated when hidden barea is shown
            //if (IsPopupSearchVisible)
            //{
            //    await cNavBarSlider.TranslateTo(-cCell.Width + 40, 0, 0, null);
            //}

            _titlebar_changingsize = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Nick, This looks promising - do you have any idea if it's possible to do with xaml markup? Also what happens to be your cTitleBarMain?  Also I am curious how do you go back to normal state? What does your cancel button do, does it show only the first column?

Comment: as you can see the cTitleBarMain just slides by code... edited post above to be more clear. My bad this page uses a disabled scrollview, ill edit the post above asap.

Comment: Believe there are many other solutions available, especially using absolute layout, this is just one of them..

Comment: Thanks very much for providing this sample. I am having issues getting this to work.  Maybe the problem is this wont work in a ViewCell?  I essentially copied most of the code above but it doesn't appear to work as desired.  Just shows the image I added after  <!-- your hidden content to appear put here --!> and my listview contains no text.

Comment: post you xaml so we could help

Comment: Sorry for the delay.  Here is the ViewCell I have in my listview https://pastebin.com/uY5e98u3  Does not appear to even display the test label for some reason

Comment: You have a mistake in your code. Closed the main <Grid> grid tag before the childs you wanted to include inside of it, so they stayed out of the swiping layout.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159377/discussion-between-nick-kovalsky-and-jessica-s).

Comment: Thank you very much. This approach helped me very much.  I ended up using AbsoluteLayout to achieve this and used TranslateTo how you suggested. Thank you!

Comment: Nick after implementing this I found that there is an issue with ViewCell being repeated.  Have you seen issues like this?  I opened new post and hoped maybe you would know https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47478881/viewcell-in-listview-repeats-for-nth-row-for-the-actions